# What happens to a batch having a settlementState of settlementError?

Tags: authorize.net

**In the [Authorize.net API](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html), when `getSettledBatchList` returns a `settlementState` of `settlementError`, is that the final state for the batch?  What should I expect to happen to the batched transactions?**

Is the same batch processed again the following day, using the same batch id, possibly resulting in a `settlementState` of `settledSuccessfully`?  Or are the affected transactions automatically included in a new batch with a new batch id?

If the transactions are included in a new batch, would they then be included in multiple batches?  If transactions are included in multiple batches, would `getTransactionList` for each of these batches return the exact same `transactionStatus` for transactions that were included in multiple batches, regardless of which batch id was used to make the `getTransactionList` request?

Question was originally asked at https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/What-happens-to-a-batch-having-a-settlementState-of/td-p/58993. If the question is answered there, I'll also add the answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer posted in the Authorize.Net community for those who did not follow the [link in the question](https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/What-happens-to-a-batch-having-a-settlementState-of/td-p/58993):

> Batch status of "settlement error" means that the batch failed. There are different reasons a batch could fail depending on the processor the merchant is using and different causes of failure. A failed batch needs to be reset and this means that the merchant will need to contact Authorize.Net to request for a batch reset. It is important to note that batches over 30 days old cannot be reset. When resetting a batch, merchant needs to confirm first with their MSP (Merchant Service Provider) that the batch was not funded, and the error that failed the batch has been fixed, before submitting a ticket for the batch to be reset.
>
> Resetting a batch doesn't really modify the batch, what it does, is it takes the transactions from the batch and puts them back into unsetttled so they settle with the next batch. Those transactions that were in the failed batch will still have the original submit date.

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.net just sends the batch  to your msp, you'll have to contact your msp to have them three way call authorize.net to sort it out.